# how to repaint all the UI componenets in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsplumb

I have a several divs connected to one another using the endpoint connections to one another. As I do a zoom in or zoom out, I need to repaint all the UI components. The UI components are drawn using the jsPlumb library(jquery/javascript based). There is a method in jsplumb which forces the repaint but it is not working as the way I want it to do. Here it is what I am trying to do.

```
    $("div#explanation .plus").click(function(){
        jsPlumb.repaintEverything();
            var strongFont = parseFloat($("div.window strong").css('font-size'));
            var newStrongFont = strongFont + 2;
            $("div.window ").animate({
                    'height':'+=20px', 'width':'+=20px'
                },"medium");

            $("div.window strong").animate({
                    fontSize:newStrongFont
                },"medium");

    //This is not working       
            jsPlumb.repaintEverything();
            jsPlumb.repaintEverything();
            //I am calling here another function to repaint the div windows one by one
            repaintWindows();

     });
        var repaintWindows = function(){
            var jjl;
            for(jjl=1;jjl<=xmlLength;jjl++)
            {
                var windo = "window"+jjl;
                //alert("Window is ::"+windo);

                jsPlumb.repaint(windo);
                alert("Window is ::"+windo);
                //_addEndpoints(wind, ["LeftMiddle", "BottomCenter"], ["TopCenter", "RightMiddle"]);
            }
            alert("the value of jjl is ::"+jjl+" \nThe value of xmlLength is::"+xmlLength);
        };
```

The problem here is if I remove the

```
        //alert("Window is ::"+windo);
```

from the repaintWindows method for loop, the windows get repainted during the next cycle of call. I want the repaint to work at the same time. If I keep the alert, then it does repaint the window at the same time. As well, at the end I dont want any kind of alert over there. 
Can somebody please tell me where am I going wrong. 
Any help is appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: I got this done. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

not sure, but try this one

```
 $(window).resize(function() {
  jsPlumb.repaintEverything();
 });
```